# do I need to initialize the new view?

Tags: objective-c, image, view, initialization, landscape

I admit I'm a newby to Objective-C but came pretty far, I guess. Now I'm having an issue and would need some help.

In my app I display images in portrait modes amongst other information and want to display them full screen in landscape mode. I learned that you'd do this defining a Landscape m, h and nib file and load this view when the device is moved to landscape orientation (working with an observer), right?

In portrait mode the images in the end depend on user interaction so the Landscape class needs to be told, which image to display. I created a putImage method in the Landscape class

```
-(void) putImage:(NSString *)theImage {

    pict.image = [UIImage imageNamed: theImage];

    NSLog(@"PICT  %@",pict.image);
    NSLog(@"IMAGE %@",theImage);
}
```

and call it from the portrait one and here comes the issue:

```
NSString *actualImage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Picture%i.jpg",selected];
pict.image = [UIImage imageNamed: actualImage];
[landscapeViewController putImage:actualImage];
```

that works perfectly every time **except the very first** one. So whatever I do I need to first make the App load a new image plus change to landscape orientation (being displayed no image) in any manner. Then after it always works displaying the correct images.

I added debug information and see that the correct image is assigned to pict in landscape class - however it seems it needs to be displayed before it really sets the image.

Any help you guys could give?

Comment: show us how you initialise your LandscapeViewController class, also is it the same as the Landscape class you mention in your question or is that just a view? Need to see code for that too. I suspected you're not setting the CGRect for the view when the UIView instance is initialised (if you in fact have one).

Comment: Hi. This is all - doing it in viewDidLoad of the portrait:  

LandscapeViewController *viewController = [[LandscapeViewController alloc]
                                               initWithNibName:@"LandscapeView" bundle:nil];
 self.landscapeViewController = viewController;
 [viewController release];

then next step is display:


    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(deviceOrientation) && !isShowingLandscapeView)
 {
        [self presentModalViewController:self.landscapeViewController animated:YES];}

Comment: And yes, the LndsacpeViewController class in the end only has a ViewWillAppear ViewWillDisappear and the putImage methods and in the xib file an image filling the whole content area.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this it it since your example code is pretty sparse. But when you load your first picture do you do that in init? If so, try to do it in viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear.

Comment: Nope - as displayed above I intend to set the image from the class that calls the landscape view using the putImage method from the landscape view class. I do not have any init defined ... could that already be the problem?

Comment: Well that is a bit hard to describe - the code is the 3 lines above

  NSString *actualImage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Picture%i.jpg",selected];
  pict.image = [UIImage imageNamed: actualImage];
        [landscapeViewController putImage:actualImage];

it is first called within some kind of initialization of the portrait view class in the overwritten viewDidLoad method (it is always the same code I call for setting the image)

Comment: I would need some code in order to help you more, I noticed you are using something called selected here:
`NSString *actualImage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Picture%i.jpg",selected];`

Is that initialized on the first run ?

Comment: Ah, ok - that is a a UISegmentedControll, I do not (explicitly) initialize it but it is 0 in the beginning.

Comment: The whole method I set the stuff in is a bit too long for 500 chars ... but there is not more than than above code (in fact I have to distinct b/w selector being 0 and greater than 0) but this does not influence the resulting issue ;o(

Comment: You can edit your question to add relevant code. It will be easier for other people to help you if you do that instead of putting bits of code in the comments section.

Comment: Ok - thanks for this hint ;o) - however it seems I solved it. Will post my solution.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for all the hints and tries to help. Now I found the solution myself ... here's what I did:

1) in the LandscapeViewController.h I defined an NSString:

```
@interface LandscapeViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UIImageView *pict;
    NSString *actualImage;
}
```

2) I changed the putImage method to only assign the image name to my local NSSTRING variable:

```
-(void) putImage:(NSString *)theImage {

    actualImage = theImage;

    [actualImage retain];
}
```

3) loading the image I only do in viewWillAppear:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    pict.image = [UIImage imageNamed: actualImage];

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

So the answer to my question is almost answered - I guess that this issue arose because I did set the image before I loaded the view first time so that it was not instanciated. I was able to call the method but had no Image Object to set ... does that sound logical to you guys?

Thank you all again!